# Checking out jDownloader with Netbeans

Tags: java, svn, netbeans, svn-checkout

I checked out the jDownloader site and they show you how to check out the project with Eclipse but not Netbeans. Can anyone offer some assistance as to how one does it with Netbeans (step by step)?

It's my first time checking out a project so I apologize ahead of time if it is a stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an step by step guide to checkout from svn from the following link:

[Link # 1](http://solitarygeek.com/java/subversion-and-netbeans-a-quick-start-guide)

Also you can find more on netbeans IDE and SVN from netbeans [Users FAQ](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansUserFAQ). A good [article](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html) also on netbeans knowledge base.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, I understand the basics of how to check out using svn, but I get confused with jDownloader. They explain somewhat how to do so with Eclipse. I asked because I'm un-aware of how the file structure is set up. I can link to the tutorial, but I'm unsure how to do it in Netbeans because the commands are slightly different.